# Threads are getting hung for ReentrantReadWriteLock$FairSync

Tags: java, multithreading

While accessing JMX service using "cmdline-jmxclient-0.10.3.jar", it doesn't respond indefinitely.
In thread dump we observed that all these threads are in WAITING  state which are waiting for ReentrantReadWriteLock$FairSync.

**JRE details:**
Java Version Is: 1.8.0_45
Java Vendor Is: Oracle Corporation

This is intermittent problem, observed only once.

**Is this known JDK issue?**

Stack trace:

```
"RMI TCP Connection(733561)-10.219.11.2" #130543 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f513007a800 nid=0x64d0 waiting on condition [0x00007f4f7e8e5000]
       java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000000c050e3e0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock$FairSync)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:836)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireShared(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:967)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireShared(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1283)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock$ReadLock.lock(ReentrantReadWriteLock.java:727)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Repository.query(Repository.java:528)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.queryMBeansImpl(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:511)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.queryMBeans(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:503)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.queryMBeans(JmxMBeanServer.java:592)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1481)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1307)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1399)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.queryMBeans(RMIConnectionImpl.java:535)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor100.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:323)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$241(TCPTransport.java:683)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$$Lambda$1/2095057400.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Thanks in advance,
Vikas

Comment: It's probably not the relevant stack trace, look for any with your codebase in them.

Comment: What's more likely?  A bug in the JVM, with probably hundreds of millions if not billions of copies installed worldwide, or a deadlock bug in your code, with likely just a handful of instances?

Comment: Ok your RMI server is blocked on a reentrant lock, what does this do to your code and why is it relevant? What are you building and what is your code that you used to implement it?

Comment: I think ReentrantReadWriteLock can't enter into 'read' lock though no one has acquired write lock. Same problem is reported in Oracle JDK bug DB: http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8149018